# Add a banner to the Dashboard

Tags: widgets, dashboard

Is there a way to add a banner to the WP dashboard? I don't mean in a custom widget or anything, just a simple image banner.

Comment: You'll have to add a widget and then add the img html string wrapped as meta box callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround using jQuery DOM insertion.
*Note the use of PHP [Heredoc sintax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to print the script.*

```
function wpse_53035_script_enqueuer(){
    echo <<<HTML
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        $('<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;"><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/wordpress/img/logo.png?v=123"></div>').insertBefore('#welcome-panel');
    });     
    </script>
HTML;
}
add_action('admin_head-index.php', 'wpse_53035_script_enqueuer');
```

This inserts the new div at the top before `#welcome-panel`. If you use the div `#dashboard-widgets-wrap` it prints in the same position (after `<h2>Dashboard</h2>` and before the widgets).
The welcome panel is normally hidden, but I'm not sure of its general behavior. I guess this depends on your tests.

---

*[edit]*
As a matter of fact, just inspect the page and insert wherever you want.

---

*[edit 2]*
Playing with the code...
The following version does a fade-in of the widgets wrap. It also adds the **width and height in the image tag**, so other elements don't "jump" when the image finally loads.

```
function wpse_53035_script_enqueuer(){
    echo <<<HTML
    <style type="text/css">#dashboard-widgets-wrap {display:none;}</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        $('#dashboard-widgets-wrap').delay(1200).fadeTo('slow',1);
        $('<div style="width:100%;text-align:center;margin:8px 0"><img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/wordpress/img/logo.png?v=123" width="483" height="43"></div>').insertBefore('#dashboard-widgets-wrap');
    });     
    </script>
HTML;
}
add_action('admin_head-index.php', 'wpse_53035_script_enqueuer');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hook into the `admin_head` action and include some custom CSS to attach a background image to the `div` with an id of `wpbody-content`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head-%28plugin_page%29